# Calendar display in Android App only through Calendar View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-calendar, calendarview

I would like to display a calendar in an android app. Based on some research, I found that we can use the CalendarView widget to display a calendar. We cannot create events, attendees or other features using the CalendarView, correct me if I am wrong. The other option is to use the native in built calendar using Intents.

1. Is there any other way to display a calendar easily in an Android app easily without the above 2 methods and still be able to create events, attendees or other features.
2. Can CalendarProvider be used create a calendar display. I know it can be used to create events, attendees, reminders etc...
3. Can CalenderProvider be used in conjunction with CalendarView?
4. If CalendarProvider cannot be used in conjunction with CalendarView or any other easy way, should we build a calendar from scratch?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Based on some research, I found that we can use the CalendarView widget to display a calendar.

You can use `CalendarView` to allow the user to pick a date.

> We cannot create events, attendees or other features using the CalendarView, correct me if I am wrong

`CalendarView` is a widget. Its job is not to "create events, attendees" — similarly, it is not the job of `EditText` to create Wikipedia pages. The job of `CalendarView` is to let the user pick a date using a calendar-style visual representation.

> Is there any other way to display a calendar easily in an Android app easily without the above 2 methods and still be able to create events, attendees or other features

You are certainly welcome to see if there is [an existing library](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=calendar) that has your desired feature set.

> Can CalendarProvider be used create a calendar display

Not directly. This is akin to asking "can I use an Excel spreadsheet to create a calendar display?" `CalendarProvider` is a data store. It is not a visual representation of an event calendar.

> Can CalenderProvider be used in conjunction with CalendarView?

Not in the way that you are thinking. `CalendarView` is a way to allow the user to pick a date. It is not a way to show the user information about particular dates (e.g., appointments or other events).

> should we build a calendar from scratch?

That is up to you.